# How does to download and extract .tar files in a container for Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

Over here is a use case - I want to download and extract all files from a particular website and allow users to specify from which workweek it might be done. Please, imagine using one docker command and specifying only the variable which tells where to go, download and extract files.

The problem is I want to allow a user to manipulate variables that refer to a particular workweek.

****Now it is only my idea**, not sure If I am thinking right before I start to design my Dockerfile.**

Dockerfile:

> ...
> ENV TARGET="$WW_DIR"
> ...

Now you can imagine that the first user wants to download files from WW17 so he can type:

> docker container run -e TARGET=WW17 <image_name>

The second one wants to download files from WW25:

> docker container run -e TARGET=WW25 <image_name>

Etc.

Underhood Dockerfile knows that it must go to the directory from WW17 (in the first scenario) or WW25 (in the second scenario). My imagination is that a new container is created then using for example "curl" files are downloaded from an external server and extracted.

Can you recommend to me the best methods with some examples of how to solve it? Apply bash script inside of the container?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I did it. Even I added suggestions but I want to hear others' solutions to that use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Dockerfile at `docker container run`, it just runs the command. So write a command that does what you want  **or** add the data to the image when building it with Dockerfile.

```
# Dockerfile
FROM your_favourite_image
COPY your_script /
RUN chmod +x /your_script
CMD /your_script

# your_script
#!/usr/bin/env your_favourite_langauge_like_python_or_bash_or_perl
  # download the $TARGET or whatever you want to do
```

And then

```
docker build -t image .
docker run -r TARGET=WW1 image
```

Reading: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/ https://btholt.github.io/complete-intro-to-containers/dockerfile

Comment: What if I would like to run two scripts? Let's say /your_script which you mentioned and the second one /next_script? I read that only the last CMD is run. Is that rule also apply to multi-stage Dockerfile or I can omit it with the multi-stage one?

Comment: https://www.shellscript.sh/ https://askubuntu.com/questions/88091/how-to-run-a-shell-script-in-background https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/ http://supervisord.org/ `Is that rule also apply to multi-stage Dockerfile` I do not understand. When you _run_ an image with no command then CMD is executed. In Dockerfile, you _build_ an image, CMD is saved and doesn't affect anthing.